# Swift/firebase/ ascending number of children in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database screenshot
[image]

I want to restrict user to input only up to 5 text messages. Therefore I want to add "1","2","3","4","5" ordered children with message and date value. Actually I could achieve it by some kind of manipulation through addition of the following piece of code

```
        if message0 > 1 && message0 < 7 {
        message0 = message0 - 1
    }
```

But if I skip this part then when system record data into Firebase it always skips "2" child, and then numerate them in normal ascending way.

Database screenshot

[image]

I put below my full code. It works but I feel that above manipulation is kind of strange and might be later bring troubles. If you have idea what I do wrong and some good advice who properly to add number children in ascending way I would highly appreciate.
Also want to add code which would check existing children to avoid overwriting under the same child number. But have no idea how to do it.
Anyway thanks for any advice in advance.

```
  func sendInputTextToFirebase() { 
        var message0 = MyGlobalVariables.refMessages.child(MyGlobalVariables.uidUser!).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            var a = [String]()
            a.append(snapshot.key)
            print(a)
            let b = a.count
            print(b)
                }

    //TODO: make child counting into dbase upto 5 in more elegant way
    if message0 > 1 && message0 < 7 {
        message0 = message0 - 1
    }

    if message0 < 6 {
    let messageString = String(message0)
    let picker = tergetDateTF.text
    let messageT = [
                "message": messageTV.text! as String,
                "Date": picker]
    MyGlobalVariables.refMessages.child(MyGlobalVariables.uidUser!).child(messageString).setValue(messageT)

        } else {

        print("limit exceeded")
        }}}
```

Comment: There is really an issue with key name `2` in Firebase. So do not use numbers as key, use autogenerated keys instead.

Comment: Please do NOT include images and links in questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

As the user in the comment suggests you can use autoId to add your message, something like this:

```
MyGlobalVariables.refMessages.child(MyGlobalVariables.uidUser!).childByAutoId().setValue(messageT)
```

As for the counting of the messages you can do something like this:

First make the next var a global variable

```
func sendInputTextToFirebase() { 
    var message0 = MyGlobalVariables.refMessages.child(MyGlobalVariables.uidUser!).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        a.append(snapshot.key)
        print(a)
if(a.count < 6) {
    let messageString = String(message0)
    let picker = tergetDateTF.text
    let messageT = [
            "message": messageTV.text! as String,
            "Date": picker]
MyGlobalVariables.refMessages.child(MyGlobalVariables.uidUser!).childByAutoId().setValue(messageT)
} else {
   print("limit exceeded")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two solutions

1) Read the node and get the child count. If < 6 then allow the write

```
let uid = "some user id"
let usersRef = self.ref.child("textmessages")
messagesRef.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let count = snapshot.childrenCount
    if count < 6 {
        //write the data
    } else {
        print("You've already got 5 messages")
    }
})
```

2) Keep a counter of the number of messages, update it when a message is added. Here's a structure:

```
textmessages
  uid_0
    msg_id_0
       msg: "Hello"
    msg_id_1
       msg: "Goodbye"

messagecounter
    uid_0
       msg_count: 2
```

When when the user logs in, read their message count and only allow messages to be added if the count < 6